# Why DataTable to Object not mapping?

Tags: datatable, automapper

Here is my object

```
public class MemberInfo
{
    public int MemberID;
    public string FullName;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public string Password;
    public string Phone;
    public string PostalCode;
    public MembershipType? MembershipType;
    public PlanType PlanType;
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int? Veh_ID { get; set; }

    public int TempmemberID { get; set; }
}
```

Hfere is the AutoMapper code

```
 List<MemberInfo> result = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<MemberInfo>>(Dt.CreateDataReader());
```

the Dt [DataTable] actually have values when I breakpoint.  It has only 1 row.

the 'result' has one item with all of the property values set to default [null & 0].

Does Dt have to be exactly matching all properties of the MemberInfo obj?
Because only some columns match.

I was hoping it will map at least the matched columns.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. A datatable and a class both containing non-matching column/property names map OK (AutoMapper 3.11). I assume that an exception occurs when the first row is mapped.

Comment: Could it be it was first mapping the values, and then again it mapped some default values?

Note, there is no Exception.  I just get the object with default values.